# Create code template from input javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make app that generates code with HTML tags from images.

User pastes an image link, image displays and after that user will click button to generate the `img` code to copy.

I've got code that loads and previews images from input.

I'm struggling with generating the HTML code. User will get:
`<img src="link photo">` in div code.

I can't make it:

```
document.getElementById('code').innerHTML = '<img src=" ' + source + '">';
```

Because it won't display HTML tags.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <style>
      img {
      width: 10%;
      height: 10%;
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      opacity: 85%;
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="imagename" value="" />
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Show" />
  </form>
  <div id="before">
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>HTML`s code to copy:</p>
  </div>
  <div name="code" id="code">
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("click", fun);

    function fun() {
      var val = document.getElementById('imagename').value;
      source = val;
      img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = source;
      document.body.appendChild(img);
      // move child to up
      var before = document.getElementById('before');
      before.insertBefore(img, before.children[0]);

      document.getElementById('code').innerHTML = '<img src=" ' + source + '">';

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `innerHTML`, use `innerText`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <style>
      img {
      width: 10%;
      height: 10%;
      border-radius: 10px;
      box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      opacity: 85%;
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="imagename" value="" />
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="Show" />
  </form>
  <div id="before">
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>HTML`s code to copy:</p>
  </div>
  <div name="code" id="code">
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("click", fun);

    function fun() {
      var val = document.getElementById('imagename').value;
      source = val;
      img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = source;
      document.body.appendChild(img);
      // move child to up
      var before = document.getElementById('before');
      before.insertBefore(img, before.children[0]);

      document.getElementById('code').innerText = '<img src="' + source + '">';

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I was trying to do in same way with <style> tag but it doesnt work. Any solutions?

Comment: What do you want your style tag to look like?

Comment: I`ve got style tag and want to print on display as like as used to innerText to copy and paste.